# Java String hashCode of null string

Tags: java, string, static, null

Only interesting, why method hashCode() in java.lang.String is not static?
And in case of null return e.g. -1 ?
Because frequently need do somethihg like:

```
String s;
.............
if (s==null) {
  return 0;}
else {
  return s.hashCode();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It wouldn't be a very useful hash if static.  (And note that hashCode is a method of Object.)

Comment: (You can, of course, write your own static myHash method that checks its parameter for null.)

Comment: `static int hashCodeOf( Object o ) { return (o != null) ? o.hashCode() : 0; }`

Comment: @oliholz: and *if* you do it, make it accept an `Object`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others have noted `hashCode` is a method on `Object` and is non-static because it inherently relies (i.e. belongs to) an object/instance.

Note that Java 7 introduced the [`Objects`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) class, which has the [`hashCode(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) method, which does exactly what you want: return `o.hashCode()` if `o` is non-null or `0` otherwise.

This class also has other methods that deal with possibly-`null` values, such as [`equals(Object, Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29), [`toString(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%29) and a few others.

Comment: " return o.hashCode() if o is non-null or 0 otherwise." How can you call hashCode() on a null and get 0?

Comment: @HelenCui: you can't call `hashCode` on `null`, obviously. That's why you call the *static* method on the class called `Objects` and pass the possibly-null value in: `int hash = Objects.hashCode(aVariableThatMightBeNull)`. If the variable *was* null then `hash` will be `0`, otherwise it will be the value returned by its `hashCode()` method.

Answer (score 8):

because if it was static `"1".hashCode()` and `"2".hashCode()` would have returned the same value, which is obviously wrong.

It is specific per instance, and influenced by it, therefore it cannot be static.

Comment: Wrong: if a static `hashCode(String)` was provided along the non-static [String.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29), it could be called like this `String.hashCode("1")`, or, if you ignore the warning, `"2".hashCode("1")`. Both calls would return the same value.

Comment: @bernardpaulus But the questions is not about `hashCode(String)`, it's about `hashCode()` (unparametrized).

Comment: a no-parameter static `String.hashCode()` does not make much sense (should not even compile as it cannot override [Object.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) ). Plus the `foo()` notation is often used to indicate that `foo` is a function, without specifying the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Because the hash code of a String is a property of that String.

With the same train of thought you could make every method static.

Answer (score 2):

`hashCode` is used to get the hashCode of an object, in order to know in which bucket of a `HashMap` this object must be placed. It thus has to be an instance method of the object, and it must be called polymorphically.

`null` can be used as a key in a HashMap, but it's treated as a special case.

You seem to be using hashCode for a different purpose, so you have to handle is in a specific way.

Answer (score 1):

Its returning hashCode of an `Object` not an class.