# Apply function to each row of Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm on Spark 1.3.

I would like to apply a function to each row of a dataframe. This function hashes each column of the row and returns a list of the hashes.

```
dataframe.map(row => row.toSeq.map(col => col.hashCode))
```

I get a NullPointerException when I run this code. I assume that this is related to [SPARK-5063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5063).

I can't think of a way to achieve the same result without using a nested map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't an instance of SPARK-5063 because you're not nesting RDD transformations; the inner `.map()` is being applied to a Scala `Seq`, not an RDD.

My hunch is that some rows in your data set contain null column values, so some of the `col.hashCode` calls are throwing NullPointerExceptions when you try to evaluate `null.hashCode`. In order to work around this, you need to take nulls into account when computing hashcodes.

If you're running on a Java 7 JVM or higher ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6982081/590203)), you can do

```
import java.util.Objects
dataframe.map(row => row.toSeq.map(col => Objects.hashCode(col)))
```

Alternatively, on earlier versions of Java you can do

```
    dataframe.map(row => row.toSeq.map(col => if (col == null) 0 else col.hashCode))
```